# react-router-dom <Link> Not Updating Page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

**Description of problem:**

Changing the id (numbers only) of this url via the link tag does not update the page (but does change the url in the adress bar). Hitting refresh afterward will show the updated page.

```
http://localhost:8080/video/id/7564
```

Right clicking to open the link in a new tab, or changing the link path to a completely different page works as expected.

My app.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import RenderHomepage from '../components/homePage/RenderHomepage'
import RenderChannelPage from '../components/channelPage/RenderChannelPage'
import RenderVideoPage from '../components/videoPage/RenderVideoPage'
import RenderSearchPage from '../components/searchPage/RenderSearchPage'
import PageNotFound from '../components/PageNotFound'
import history from '../history'

const App = () => {
  return ( 
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={RenderHomepage} /> 
          <Route path="/channel" component={RenderChannelPage} /> 
          <Route path="/video/id" component={RenderVideoPage} /> 
          <Route path="/search" component={RenderSearchPage} /> 
          <Route path="/404" exact component={PageNotFound} />
          <Route component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Link tag in UpNextVideos component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

...
  <Link to={{pathname: vid.id}}> 
    <h3 className={`${p}-sidebar-grid-video-title`}>{capitalizeFirstLetter(vid.tags)}</h3>
  </Link>
...
```

How the components in question are nested:

```
<RenderVideoPage>
  <VideoPage>
    <UpNextVideos>
```

RenderVideoPage component:

```
import React from 'react'
import VideoPage from './VideoPage'
import Header from '../Header'
import HeaderMobile from '../HeaderMobile'
import FooterMobile from '../FooterMobile'
import ActivityFeed from '../ActivityFeed'

const RenderVideoPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="videoPage-body">
      <HeaderMobile />
      <Header />
      <ActivityFeed page={'home'} />
      <VideoPage />
      <FooterMobile page={'video'} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default RenderVideoPage
```

VideoPage component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import history from '../../history'
import handleMediaQueries from './containers/handleMediaQueries'
import setDislikes from './containers/setDislikes'

import NewSubscribers from './NewSubscribers'
import CommentSection from './CommentSection'
import UpNextVideos from './UpNextVideos'
import DescriptionBox from './DescriptionBox'
import VideoNotFound from './VideoNotFound'

import { fetchVideoFromID, fetchPictureFromID } from '../../containers/api'
import { thumbsUp, thumbsDown } from '../svgs'

import { 
  abbreviateNumber, 
  capitalizeFirstLetter, 
  randomDate } from '../../containers/helperFunctions'

const VideoPage = () => {
  const [p, setPrefix] = useState("videoPage")
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    error: false
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.loading) extractDataFromUrl()
    else handleMediaQueries()
  }, [state.loading])

  const fetchVideo = async (id, picAuthorID) => {
    let response = await fetchVideoFromID(id)
    if (!response) setState(prevState => ({...prevState, error: true}))
    else mapVideoResponseToHTML(response.data.hits, picAuthorID)
  }

  const mapVideoResponseToHTML = (response, picAuthorID) => {
    let responseAsHtml = response.map(vid => {
      return {
        video: 
        <div className={`${p}-video-wrapper posRelative`} key={vid.id}>
          <a className={`${p}-pixabay-src`} href={vid.pageURL}>?</a>
          <video 
            poster="https://i.imgur.com/Us5ckqm.jpg" 
            className={`${p}-video clickable`} 
            src={vid.videos.large.url} 
            controls autoPlay>
          </video>
          <div className={`${p}-video-info-wrapper`}>  
            <div className={`${p}-video-title-box`}>
              <h1 className={`${p}-video-title`}>{capitalizeFirstLetter(vid.tags)}</h1>
              <span className={`${p}-video-views`}>{abbreviateNumber(Number(vid.downloads).toLocaleString())} views</span>
              <span className={`${p}-video-date`}>{randomDate()}</span>
            </div>
            <div className={`${p}-video-options`}>
              <div className="thumbs">
                <div className={`${p}-video-options-thumbsUp`}>{thumbsUp(20)} &nbsp; 
                  <span className={`${p}-video-options-thumbsUp-text`}>{abbreviateNumber(vid.likes)}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={`${p}-video-options-thumbsDown`}>{thumbsDown(20)} &nbsp; 
                  <span className={`${p}-video-options-thumbsDown-text`}>{setDislikes(vid.likes)}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={`${p}-video-options-likebar`}></div>
              </div>
              <span className={`${p}-video-options-share`}>Share</span>
              <span className={`${p}-video-options-save`}>Save</span>
              <span className={`${p}-video-options-ellipses`}>...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>,
        authorFollowers: vid.views,
        vidAuthorID: vid.id,
        author: picAuthorID ? 'Loading' : vid.user,
        authorAvatar: picAuthorID ? null : vid.userImageURL,
        views: vid.downloads
      }
    })
    responseAsHtml = responseAsHtml[0]
    setState(prevState => ({...prevState, ...responseAsHtml, loading: false}))
    if (picAuthorID) fetchAuthorAvatar(picAuthorID)
  }

  const extractDataFromUrl = () => {
    const currentURL = window.location.href
    const urlAsArray = currentURL.split('/')
    const urlID = urlAsArray[5].split('-')
    const videoID = urlID[0]
    const picAuthorID = urlID[1]

    // Author avatars are random except on the home page. 
    // if url isnt from homepage, then use videoID
    // if url is from homepage, send that avatarID
    if (urlID.includes('000')) {
      fetchVideo(videoID)
    } else {
      setState(prevState => ({...prevState, picAuthorID: picAuthorID}))
      fetchVideo(videoID, picAuthorID)
    }
  }

  const fetchAuthorAvatar = async (id) => {
    const response = await fetchPictureFromID(id)
    const authorName = response.data.hits[0].user
    const authorAvatar = response.data.hits[0].previewURL
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState, 
      authorAvatar: authorAvatar, 
      author: capitalizeFirstLetter(authorName)
    }))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { state.error ? <VideoNotFound /> : null}
      { state.loading === true ? null
        : 
        <div className={`${p}-page-wrapper`}>
          <main className={`${p}-main`}>
            {state.video}
            <DescriptionBox props={state} />
            <div className={`${p}-suggested-videos-mobile`}></div>

            <div className={`${p}-new-subscribers-wrapper`}>
              <h2 className={`${p}-new-subscribers-text`}>{`New Subscribers to ${state.author}`}</h2>
              <NewSubscribers />
            </div>
            <div className={`${p}-comment-section`}>
              <CommentSection views={state.views}/>
            </div>
          </main>
          <aside className={`${p}-sidebar`}>
           <UpNextVideos />
          </aside>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoPage
```

UpNextVideos component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import { videoQuery } from '../../words'
import { fetchVideos } from '../../containers/api'
import { 
  capitalizeFirstLetter, 
  uuid,
  getRandom,
  abbreviateNumber
} from '../../containers/helperFunctions'

const UpNextVideos = () => {
  const [p, setPrefix] = useState("videoPage")
  const [nextVideos, setNextVideos] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUpNextVideos(15, getRandom(videoQuery))
  }, [])

  // INFINITE SCROLL
  const observer = useRef()
  const lastUpNextVideo = useCallback(lastVideoNode => {

    // Re-hookup observer to last post, to include fetch data callback
    if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect()
    observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      const lastVideo = entries[0]
        if (lastVideo.isIntersecting && window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
          document.querySelector('.videoPage-show-more-button').classList.add('show')
        }
        else if (lastVideo.isIntersecting && window.innerWidth > 1000) {
          document.querySelector('.videoPage-show-more-button').classList.remove('show')
          fetchUpNextVideos(20, getRandom(videoQuery))
      }
    })
    if (lastVideoNode) observer.current.observe(lastVideoNode)
  })

  const fetchUpNextVideos = async (amount, query) => {
    let response = await fetchVideos(amount, ...Array(2), query)
    response = response.data.hits

    const responseAsHtml = response.map((vid, index) => {
      return (
        <div className={`${p}-sidebar-grid-video-wrapper`} key={uuid()} ref={response.length === index + 1 ? lastUpNextVideo : null}>
          <div className={`${p}-sidebar-grid-video`}>
            <a href={`/video/id/${vid.id}-000`}>
              <video 
                className={`${p}-upnext-video`} 
                onMouseOver={event => event.target.play()}
                onMouseOut={event => event.target.pause()}
                src={`${vid.videos.tiny.url}#t=1`}
                muted >
              </video>
            </a>
          </div>
          <a href={`/video/id/${vid.id}`}>
            <h3 className={`${p}-sidebar-grid-video-title`}>{capitalizeFirstLetter(vid.tags)}</h3>
          </a>
          <a href={`/channel/000${vid.id}`}>
            <p className={`${p}-sidebar-grid-video-author`}>{vid.user}</p>
          </a>
          <p className={`${p}-sidebar-grid-video-views-text`}>{abbreviateNumber(vid.downloads)} views</p>
        </div>
      )
    })
    setNextVideos(prevState => ([...prevState, ...responseAsHtml]))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={`${p}-sidebar-text-top`}>
        <span className={`${p}-sidebar-text-upnext`}>Up next</span>
        <span className={`${p}-sidebar-text-autoplay`}>Autoplay</span>
      </div>
      <div className={`${p}-sidebar-grid-wrapper`}>
        {nextVideos}
      </div> 
      <button 
        className={`${p}-show-more-button`} 
        onMouseDown={() => fetchUpNextVideos(15, getRandom(videoQuery))}>
        Show More
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UpNextVideos
```

What I've tried:

- Wrapping the `<Link>` tag with `<Router history={history} />`
- Wrapping the `<Link>` tag with `<BrowserRouter>`
- Wrapping the export statement `withRouter(UpNextVideos)`
- Using a plain string instead of an object, as described in [react-router-docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)

Comment: Have you try change the import to 

BrowserRouter as router    ?

Comment: Please add your `RenderVideoPage` component code, I suspect it is mounted but not looking for prop changes in the path params for the video `id`.

Comment: @HagaiHarari Not sure I understood.

Comment: @DrewReese Added the component to the question

Comment: @RobertC Ok, sorry, can you also add your `VideoPage` and `UpNextVideos` components? I'm looking to see how you access the `id` from the `match` prop.

Comment: @DrewReese Sure. Updated with the requested components.

Comment: I had the same issue, but my problem was the order of the routes. It seems the path `'/'` is always matched, so that route needs to be the last.

Comment: You can find answers in this query:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707853/react-router-dom-link-not-updating-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I believe this issue lies in your `VideoPage` component.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (state.loading) extractDataFromUrl()
  else handleMediaQueries()
}, [state.loading]);
```

You only ever have `state.loading` true once, when the component mounts. This only processes your URL once, so when the URL changes this component isn't aware of it.

This is your route currently

```
<Route path="/video/id" component={RenderVideoPage} />
```

now assuming your URLs are shaped "/video/id/" then you can define your route to have a parameter

```
 <Route path="/video/id/:videoId" component={RenderVideoPage} />
```

If you wrap this component with `react-router-dom`'s [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC you can easily get the `id` path param and add it to an effect to recompute all the video data.

```
export default withRouter(VideoPage)
```

`withRouter` injects the `location`, `match`, and `history` props from the closest `Route` ancestor. Here's an example of getting the id param and triggering an effect when its value updates.

```
const VideoPage = ({ match }) => {
  const { params } = match;

  useEffect(() => { /* do something with new id */ }, [params.videoId]);

}
```

Comment: I just did a quick test removing state.loading compeletely from that useEffect hook, but the problem remains.

Comment: I also set up a console.log on the VideoPage after wrapping it in withRouter to see what was in match and params is an empty object before and after clicking the link tags.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of realized after explaining how to get the route param that you don't actually have your routes defined to have a parameter since you are trying to process your URL from the location href. Updated my answer a bit to explain that part more.

Comment: I implemented your solution, and it does work. Although I'm left wondering in the end why <Link> didn't work on its own to update the page, and I instead had to do the update through useEffect.

Comment: Think of the path as a sort of "regex" pattern. If your route path is "/pathA/pathB", then any path with that as a root will match, i.e. "/pathA/pathB/pathC" and "/pathA/pathB/pathD". Using the `exact` prop on a route will only match explicit matches, so all sub-routes Will now not match.  Now, the reason the component doesn't rerender is because the route was only matching on the main path and not on the sub-path. When I get a chance I'll try to update my sandbox demo.

Comment: Hi Drew i have the same issue with my component but I am using ES6 code which i don't think has access to useEffect. Is there an alternative? Thanks

Comment: @Amir ES6 is a javascript syntax standard. `useEffect` is a React-only function compatible in React v16.8.4+. `useEffect` with dependency is akin to a class-based component's `componentDidUpdate`. If you like, please ask a new question here on SO and @ me here with a link to it, and I can take a look.

Comment: @Drew, yes i think i understand. Being quite new to react i find this is quite hard, when an explanation is given for a functional style and i have my code in the class style. A good documentation on how to convert these would be very handy. Thanks for your suggestion, here is my question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657309/react-router-path-with-id-is-not-working-correctly-for-component-wrapped-by-h