# <link> changes the route in the browser address bar but nothing changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using react router to navigate through my react app. When I click on the link the address changes in the browser address bar but the new component does not render

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router-dom pages won't switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782614/react-router-dom-pages-wont-switch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as a workaround you can convert the Link in your app to button link and in its onClick function you can use Redirect from react router to enforce the changing of your route so your code will be as following :

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
handleNewRoute(){
    <Redirect to={this.state.redirectLink} />
}
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782614/react-router-dom-pages-wont-switch