# React Router - Path with :id is not working correctly for component wrapped by HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I have been developing this application using react and react-router-dom The Page component is wrapped by a HOC that imports a contentservice to access a rest api.

My navigation is in the App component. The relevant part is the

```
<Link to="/page/123">About Page</Link>
```

and

```
<Link to="/page/456">Contact Page</Link>
```

When these links are clicked the page doesn't redraw as i expected. First time i go to 'About Page' it's all good.  Then when i click to go to 'Contact Page' nothing changes. Then i click on the 'About Page' again and the 'Contact Page' shows.

In all the cases above the browser address bar shows the right path and if i refresh the page i go to the right page.

Here is my navigation page:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Home from "./Home";
import Admin from "./Admin";
import Members from "./Members";
import Login from "./Login";
import Page from "./Page";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/page/123">About Page</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/page/456">Contact Page</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/members">Members</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/admin">Admin</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/page/:id" component={Page} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/members">
            <Members />
          </PrivateRoute>
          <PrivateRoute path="/admin">
            <Admin />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

This is my page component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import WithBackend from "./WithBackend";

class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.resource = "/pages/";
    this.state = { model: null };
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.model != null) {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md">
              <h1>{this.state.model.title}</h1>
              <h2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.model.body }} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Page id: {this.props.match.params.id}</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props
      .getEntity(this.resource, this.props.match.params.id)
      .then((model) => this.setState({ model }));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.props
        .getEntity(this.resource, nextProps.match.params.id)
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ model: data });
        });
    }
  }
}

export default WithBackend(Page);
```

This is the Withbackend HOC:

```js
import React from "react";
import ContentService from "./ContentService";

const WithBackend = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.contentService = new ContentService();
      this.getEntity = this.getEntity.bind(this); 
      this.getEntities = this.getEntities.bind(this); 
    }  

    getEntity(resource, id) {
      return this.contentService
        .getEntity(resource, id)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }

    getEntities(resource) {
      return this.contentService
        .getEntities(resource)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          getEntity={this.getEntity}
          getEntities={this.getEntities}
          {...this.props}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  return HOC;
};

export default WithBackend;
```

And the content service:

```js
class ContentService {
  baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

  getEntity(resource, id) {
    const path = this.baseUrl + resource + id;
    const fetchPromise = fetch(path, {
      method: "GET",
    });

    return Promise.resolve(fetchPromise);
  }

  getEntities(resource) {
    const fetchPromise = fetch(this.baseUrl + resource, {
      method: "GET",
    });

    return Promise.resolve(fetchPromise);
  }
}

export default ContentService;
```

Has anyone got any ideas why this is happening? I am not sure if it has anything to do with the Page component being wrapped by HOC but just thought it is worth mentioning.

Thank you.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` receives the previous props and state, **not** the next props. You may need to send the current `id` value, i.e. `getEntity(this.resource, this.props.match.params.id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method receives the *previous* `props`, `state`, and `snapshot` values, not the *next* ones.

[componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`

By sending the "previous" props' match param `id` you were a "cycle" behind.

## Solution

Use the current `id` value from props.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    this.props
      .getEntity(this.resource, this.props.match.params.id)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ model: data });
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: @Allema_s Do you have a new issue/question you want to ask about? If the component you are using can use React hooks then it doesn't need any `withRouter` Higher Order Component, it can use the `useParams` hook directly. If you decide to ask a new question on SO feel free to ping (@ me) me here with a link to the post and I can take a look when available.